# Using dots instead lines for indents in IntelliJ

Tags: go, intellij-idea

Using the IntelliJ Go plugin.
I like to see the indentation, but how to change the character used.

[image]

The line is too aggressive. I would prefer a dot like in the Scala or JSON plugins.

[image].

How to change it?

Using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Ultimate Edition) but the same with IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 Beta (Ultimate Edition).

Comment: ...is the difference not between spaces and tabs? I.e. they're indented differently, there's no difference between the plugins.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are 100% right. The difference is that by default, Go is using tabs. Do you know how to change it?

Comment: All doc here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/indentation.html

Comment: But looks like there is a bug. I select "Reindent to spaces" and looks it works, but when save, IntelliJ changes indentation to tabs again.

Comment: A bug in what? Go is, by strong convention, indented with tabs. If you want to edit it with spaces locally, due to the aggression of a line, maybe look into something like a [smudge and clean](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) in git.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, no. I don't mean a bug in Go. A bug in IntelliJ. When save, it reformats again using tabs no matter if you selected spaces in the configuration. Anyway, I did not know tabs was the convention. So I want to use tabs, but I don't want the IDE showing these lines but dots instead.

Comment: The lines _mean_ tabs. So you want to use tabs but have the IDE show you you're using spaces. I don't think that's going to fly.

Comment: Sorry, but "lines" does not mean "tabs". That is only the IDE representation. If they decide that "$" means "tabs", are you going to take it even it is annoying? Because someone decide "line" means "tab", Should I see my display full of lines? I want to use other character .That is all.

Comment: Using the spaces for Go language should work in the IDEA too. Try to make sure that you have disable the `Settings | Editor | Code Style | Go | Use tab character`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDEA uses the `.` as a placeholder for space, and - for tabs by default if you have the `Settings | Editor | General | Appearance | Show whitespaces` enabled.

You could change this style to something like `>` in `Settings | Advanced Settings` though it is not possible to use the dot for tab character rendering here.

[image: setting for configuring the tab rendering style]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I did not expected it in Advanced settings. Thanks!